# Can I post to G+stream using Google+ api PHP

Tags: php, google-plus

I want to create an auto publishing tool using api's fb,twitter and linkdlin gives the privileg to post to pages.Is it possible to post to google+ sream?

Comment: Any research results?

Comment: @Gnqz i didnt get any useful results

Comment: @Ghost why it is off-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Google+ api](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/) only allows for read operations.  There is no way to programmatically post to Google+ at this time.

Comment: I found the same in google+ api reference doc.But the auto post is implemented in wordpress.